# installProfile command - Failed to parse profile data (signed profile)

Tags: ios, mdm

My MDM signing certificate is expired and I want to replace the already installed MDM profile("Not Verified") with updated ones.

I look at [MDM-Protocol-Reference.pdf](https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/MDM-Protocol-Reference.pdf) and used installProfile command for it. ("The profile may also be signed")

built installProfile request using: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/install_a_profile

it works for unsigned profile (base64 encode unsigned profile).

but it didn't work for signed profile (base64 encode signed profile), received error status from the device.

and I'm able to install the new signed profile manually (using user interaction) on top of an existing profile.

Device error log:

```
Failed to parse profile data. Error: NSError:
Desc   : Invalid Profile
US Desc: Invalid Profile
Domain : MCProfileErrorDomain
Code   : 1000
Type   : MCFatalError
```

I'm Hoping to find a solution for the error OR other way to update the "Not Verified" profile without user interaction.

Device full log:

```
default 10:07:00.034059 +0300   mdmd    TIC Enabling TLS [1:0x105015240]
default 10:07:00.034108 +0300   mdmd    TIC Enabling TLS [1:0x105015240]
default 10:07:00.034868 +0300   mdmd    TIC TCP Conn Start [1:0x105015240]
default 10:07:00.034910 +0300   mdmd    TIC TCP Conn Start [1:0x105015240]
default 10:07:00.036285 +0300   mdmd    Task <83EBAB60-06B5-42EE-982A-43FA43E59CB9>.<1> setting up Connection 1
default 10:07:00.036327 +0300   mdmd    Task <83EBAB60-06B5-42EE-982A-43FA43E59CB9>.<1> setting up Connection 1
default 10:07:00.036508 +0300   mdmd    [1 <private> <private>] start
default 10:07:00.036464 +0300   mdmd    [1 <private> <private>] start
default 10:07:00.070280 +0300   mdmd    TIC TLS Event [1:0x105015240]: 11, Pending(0)
default 10:07:00.070323 +0300   mdmd    TIC TLS Event [1:0x105015240]: 11, Pending(0)
default 10:07:00.175928 +0300   mdmd    TIC TLS Trust Result [1:0x105015240]: 0
default 10:07:00.175979 +0300   mdmd    TIC TLS Trust Result [1:0x105015240]: 0
default 10:07:00.178796 +0300   mdmd    TIC TLS Event [1:0x105015240]: 13, Pending(0)
default 10:07:00.178839 +0300   mdmd    TIC TLS Event [1:0x105015240]: 13, Pending(0)
default 10:07:00.195485 +0300   mdmd    TIC TLS Event [1:0x105015240]: 20, Pending(0)
default 10:07:00.195528 +0300   mdmd    TIC TLS Event [1:0x105015240]: 20, Pending(0)
default 10:07:00.197112 +0300   mdmd    TIC TCP Conn Connected [1:0x105015240]: Err(16)
default 10:07:00.197166 +0300   mdmd    TIC TCP Conn Connected [1:0x105015240]: Err(16)
default 10:07:00.197650 +0300   mdmd    TIC TCP Conn Event [1:0x105015240]: 1
default 10:07:00.197693 +0300   mdmd    TIC TCP Conn Event [1:0x105015240]: 1
default 10:07:00.197782 +0300   mdmd    TIC TCP Conn Event [1:0x105015240]: 8
default 10:07:00.197739 +0300   mdmd    TIC TCP Conn Event [1:0x105015240]: 8
default 10:07:00.197829 +0300   mdmd    TIC TLS Handshake Complete [1:0x105015240]
default 10:07:00.197871 +0300   mdmd    TIC TLS Handshake Complete [1:0x105015240]
default 10:07:00.203814 +0300   mdmd    Task <83EBAB60-06B5-42EE-982A-43FA43E59CB9>.<1> now using Connection 1
default 10:07:00.203857 +0300   mdmd    Task <83EBAB60-06B5-42EE-982A-43FA43E59CB9>.<1> now using Connection 1
default 10:07:00.204394 +0300   mdmd    Task <83EBAB60-06B5-42EE-982A-43FA43E59CB9>.<1> sent request, body S
default 10:07:00.204453 +0300   mdmd    Task <83EBAB60-06B5-42EE-982A-43FA43E59CB9>.<1> sent request, body S
default 10:07:18.530406 +0300   mdmd    Task <83EBAB60-06B5-42EE-982A-43FA43E59CB9>.<1> received response, status 200 content U
default 10:07:18.530224 +0300   mdmd    Task <83EBAB60-06B5-42EE-982A-43FA43E59CB9>.<1> received response, status 200 content U
default 10:07:18.532521 +0300   mdmd    Task <83EBAB60-06B5-42EE-982A-43FA43E59CB9>.<1> response ended
default 10:07:18.532248 +0300   mdmd    Task <83EBAB60-06B5-42EE-982A-43FA43E59CB9>.<1> response ended
default 10:07:18.534869 +0300   mdmd    Transaction completed. Status: 200
default 10:07:18.535022 +0300   mdmd    Transaction completed. Status: 200
default 10:07:18.535773 +0300   mdmd    Starting power assertion: Request: (null)
default 10:07:18.535584 +0300   mdmd    Starting power assertion: Request: (null)
default 10:07:18.540990 +0300   mdmd    Attempting to perform MDM request: InstallProfile
default 10:07:18.541106 +0300   mdmd    Attempting to perform MDM request: InstallProfile
default 10:07:18.572015 +0300   mdmd    Loaded AccessibilityUtilities.framework
default 10:07:18.572117 +0300   mdmd    Loaded AccessibilityUtilities.framework
default 10:07:18.583088 +0300   mdmd    Loaded SetupAssistant.framework
default 10:07:18.583158 +0300   mdmd    Loaded SetupAssistant.framework
default 10:07:18.585012 +0300   mdmd    Loaded AssertionServices.framework
default 10:07:18.585143 +0300   mdmd    Loaded AssertionServices.framework
default 10:07:18.585359 +0300   mdmd    Loaded AssertionServices.framework
default 10:07:18.585427 +0300   mdmd    Loaded AssertionServices.framework
default 10:07:18.588152 +0300   mdmd    BKSApplicationStateMonitor 0x10510f970 dealloced without invalidate
default 10:07:18.588061 +0300   mdmd    BKSApplicationStateMonitor 0x10510f970 dealloced without invalidate
default 10:07:18.588565 +0300   mdmd    -[FMDFMIPManager isManagedLostModeActive]
default 10:07:18.588633 +0300   mdmd    -[FMDFMIPManager isManagedLostModeActive]
default 10:07:18.599702 +0300   mdmd    Failed to parse profile data. Error: NSError:
Desc   : Invalid Profile
US Desc: Invalid Profile
Domain : MCProfileErrorDomain
Code   : 1000
Type   : MCFatalErrordefault    10:07:18.599793 +0300   mdmd    Failed to parse profile data. Error: NSError:
Desc   : Invalid Profile
US Desc: Invalid Profile
Domain : MCProfileErrorDomain
Code   : 1000
Type   : MCFatalErrordefault    10:07:18.599872 +0300   mdmd    Command Status: Error
Error: NSError:
Desc   : Invalid Profile
US Desc: Invalid Profile
Domain : MCProfileErrorDomain
Code   : 1000
Type   : MCFatalError
default 10:07:18.599924 +0300   mdmd    Command Status: Error
Error: NSError:
Desc   : Invalid Profile
US Desc: Invalid Profile
Domain : MCProfileErrorDomain
Code   : 1000
Type   : MCFatalError
default 10:07:18.599994 +0300   mdmd    MCJQ 1 Enqueueing jobBlock 4, calling function -[MCMDMServer schedulePollingServerForCommandWithAssertion:]
default 10:07:18.600042 +0300   mdmd    MCJQ 1 Enqueueing jobBlock 4, calling function -[MCMDMServer schedulePollingServerForCommandWithAssertion:]
default 10:07:18.600115 +0300   mdmd    MCJQ 1 Job finished, calling function -[MCMDMServer connection:didReceiveMessageForTopic:userInfo:]_block_invoke_2
default 10:07:18.600185 +0300   mdmd    MCJQ 1 Job finished, calling function -[MCMDMServer connection:didReceiveMessageForTopic:userInfo:]_block_invoke_2
default 10:07:18.600263 +0300   mdmd    Ending power assertion: Request: (null)
default 10:07:18.600322 +0300   mdmd    Ending power assertion: Request: (null)
default 10:07:18.600381 +0300   mdmd    MCJQ 1 Dispatching to executionQueue jobBlock 4
default 10:07:18.600453 +0300   mdmd    MCJQ 1 Dispatching to executionQueue jobBlock 4
default 10:07:18.600817 +0300   mdmd    MCJQ 1 Executing jobBlock 4
default 10:07:18.600880 +0300   mdmd    MCJQ 1 Executing jobBlock 4
```